# How to disallow white space in this regular expression?

Tags: regex, wpf, vb.net, visual-studio-2015, textbox

```
Dim regex = New Regex("^[.][0-9]+$|^[0-9]*[.]{0,1}[0-9]*$")
e.Handled = Not regex.IsMatch(TryCast(sender, TextBox).Text.Insert(TryCast(sender, TextBox).SelectionStart, e.Text))
```

With this code, I am able to accept only decimal inputs for the textbox. But user is still able to enter white space to the textbox. How do I disallow that? I have tried adding in `\s` as the white space character but no luck.

**UPDATE**
Tried using this regex as suggested as well. But still able to enter white space into the textbox. Here is the code

```
Private Sub textBox4_PreviewTextInput(sender As Object, e As TextCompositionEventArgs) Handles textBox4.PreviewTextInput
    'Dim regex = New Regex("^[.][0-9]+$|^[0-9]*[.]{0,1}[0-9]*$") //This is the original code.
    Dim regex = New Regex("^\d*(\.\d*)?$")
    e.Handled = Not regex.IsMatch(TryCast(sender, TextBox).Text.Insert(TryCast(sender, TextBox).SelectionStart, e.Text))
End Sub
```

Also, there is no KeyPress event for textbox in Wpf..

Comment: [`^[.][0-9]+$|^[0-9]*[.]{0,1}[0-9]*$`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5e%5b.%5d%5b0-9%5d%2b%24%7c%5e%5b0-9%5d*%5b.%5d%7b0%2c1%7d%5b0-9%5d*%24&i=22.12) regex does not allow whitespace.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew But I am able to enter space in the textboxes..

Comment: @Student The problem is clearly in the other part of your code. What are you doing in the second line?

Comment: The code above is placed under the textbox PreviewTextInput event. @Laurel

Comment: Your regex pattern is pretty much... questionable?... That might be the best way to describe it. I would recommend the following RegEx pattern: `^\d*(\.\d*)?$`. You might be able to leave the textbox blank in that case, but it should not accept spaces. If it does still accept spaces, then there is an issue somewhere else in your code, or it is not in the proper event handler. **Note**: This will match `.` (*a single period*). If you would like to avoid that, you could do the following pattern instead: `^\d*(\.\d+)?$`.

Comment: @SpencerDoak Still able to input white space character.. Look at the update above..

Comment: That `e.Handled` line look suspicious. What happens if you make it simpler by using several lines, which will let you see what you are actually doing? I suspect that the `.Insert` actually inserts the character.